# Passing foo(int *) as argument to foo(void*) in X

Tags: c, function-pointers

A have a functions:

```
void somefunc(void func(void *)) { ... }

void foo(int *num) {...}
```

I'm trying to pass foo as an argument to somefunc but receive a warning.
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: you have some unbalanced parentheses, which is definitely not correct. Post [mcve] and the warning.

Comment: `void sumfunc(foo(X))`

Comment: `void somefunc(void (*func)(void *)) { ... }` ?  But the type mismatch between `void *` and `int *` is a problem.  You could cast if you know it will work on your machine: `somefunc((void (*)(void *))foo)` but in general it's UB since for instance `void *` and `int *` might have different calling conventions.  AFAIK the only portable way is to rewrite `foo` to expect a `void *`, or write a helper function that does.

Comment: @NateEldredge It would also be safe if `somefunc` cast it back to `void (*)(int *)` before using it.

Comment: @dxiv, if `somefunc()` is under your control and it is inclined to assume that the argument will really be a `void (*)(int *)`, then it would be better for it to declare that as the parameter type in the first place.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That would be cleaner, of course. My point, however, was that the cast *can* work if it's "reversed" before actual use ([6.3.2.3/8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8)): "*a pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer*".

Answer (score 4):

Having a parameter that is a function with one or more `void *` parameters is a common way of implementing some type-generic algorithms. (This answer assumes that to be the case in this code. Other possibilities exist but are unlikely.) The parameter `func` to `somefunc` provides a callback function that `somefunc` uses to operate on the data without knowing its type.

Note that while the parameter is declared as a function, `void func(void *)`, it is automatically adjusted to be a pointer to a function, `void (*func)(void *)`. Removing the name, we have the abstract type, `void (*)(void *)`.

You cannot pass a `void (*)(int *)` argument for a `void (*)(void *)` parameter, because they are incompatible types. And you should not attempt to coerce the `foo` argument into the parameter type with a cast, as the behavior of calling the `void (int *)` function with that converted pointer is not defined by the C standard. A proper solution is to pass a pointer to a function of the expected type. You can make a new function for this:

```
void FooWrapper(void *p) { foo(p); }
```

Then you can pass `FooWrapper` to `somefunc`. When `somefunc` calls `FooWrapper`, it will pass it a `void *`. When `FooWrapper` calls `foo`, that `void *` will be automatically converted to an `int *`. (Presumably, `foo` is declared beforehand, with a prototype.) As long as the `void *` that `FooWrapper` passes originated as a pointer to some `int`, this conversion from `void *` back to `int *` is defined by the C standard, so this is proper code.

Alternatively, instead of creating a wrapper, you can modify `foo` to take a `void *` parameter and convert it to `int *` internally:

```
void foo(void *VoidNum)
{
    int *num = VoidNum;
    …
}
```

Then you may pass `foo` directly to `somefunc`.

Comment: "*You cannot pass a `void (*)(int *)` argument for a `void (*)(void *)` parameter*" That depends on how `somefunc` uses the argument. If it casts it back to the original type then it's legal and fine.

Comment: @dxiv: No, the call is undefined regardless of what `somefunc` does internally. When `foo` is passed, it would have to be converted to the parameter type, which C 2018 6.5.2.2 7 says is done as if by assignment, but the conversion violates the constraints for assignment in 6.5.16.1 1, so the behavior is not defined. The caller could convert it with a cast, but then the behavior of calling it in the new type is undefined, per C 6.5.2.2 9. `somefunc` could reverse the conversion with its own cast, calling the function as its defined type, but the first paragraph assumes this not to be the case.

Comment: Casting a function pointer of one type to a function pointer of a different type and back is lossless and specifically allowed by [6.3.2.3/8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8).

Comment: @dxiv: There is no casting it back. As I wrote in the first paragraph, this is not the typical pattern of use and is assumed not to be the case. Further, what you are now arguing is that the later sentence about casting the pointer could be part of defined behavior. That is separate from your first comment, which is about the first sentence of the paragraph and which remains true without the assumption of the first paragraph.

Comment: The assumption that there is no cast made inside `somefunc` is not present in OP's post. Code like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zMh8jf) for example is entirely consistent with the question as posed, and is both legal and safe.

Comment: @dxiv: I judged the assumption to be appropriate and explicitly stated it in the first paragraph. If you want to write about something deliberately not covered in this answer, write your own answer. Commenting that this answer does not cover something it says it does not cover is not useful.

Comment: "And you should not attempt to coerce the foo argument into the parameter type with a cast, as the behavior of that is not defined by the C standard." is incorrect. The behaviour of the cast is well-defined.

Comment: @M.M: Remember from the first paragraph that this answer discusses the situation where `somefunc` calls the function through the parameter as it is given, a `void (*)(voud *)`. That is why converting the pointer results in undefined behavior, because of the subsequent call rather than the conversion itself. I added text to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to pass foo as an argument to somefunc but receive a warning.

The error occurs because `somefunc` is declared to expect an argument of type `void (*)(void *)`, but the argument `foo` being passed has the type `void (*)(int *)`. The two types are different and incompatible.

> What is the correct way to do this?

Function pointers can be cast between different types, so the following will compile without error.

```
void bar()  { somefunc((void (*)(int *))foo); }
```

Using an auxiliary `typedef` makes the same code more readable.

```
typedef void (*VOID_FUNC)(void *);

void bar()  { somefunc((VOID_FUNC)foo); }
```

The important caveat is that ***the only*** legal/safe use of the `func` argument inside `somefunc` is to cast it back to the real type of the original function before using it. From the relevant paragraph [6.3.2.3/8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8) in the language standard: "*A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.* ***If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.***"

Below is an abbreviated example of correct usage.

```
extern int n;
void foo(int *num);

typedef void (*VOID_FUNC)(void *);
typedef void (*INT_FUNC)(int *);

void somefunc(VOID_FUNC func)  { ((INT_FUNC)func)(&n); }

void bar()  { somefunc((VOID_FUNC)foo); }
```

Comment: A complete code example is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WorhrW).

Comment: "The important caveat is that the only legal/safe use of the func argument inside somefunc is to cast it back to the real type of the original function before using it." - sure, but if `somefunc` was going to do that, it would have just been defined to take a `void(*)(int *)` in the first place.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica For one single type, of course. But `somefunc` could be something like in the code linked in my first comment, and wrap different calls for logging/profiling/etc purposes. Or it could be a helper function in a variant-style context. Or any number of other scenarios where there would be several types involved, all known in advance.